# How could you start all of the scripts in /etc/rc2.d?

Tags: bash, rc, runlevel, inittab

So I am in /etc/rc3.d and I want to start all of the "S" scripts and Kill all of the "K" scripts. I am trying `# ./S* start` but it's not seeing the start argument. How to I adjust my syntax to allow me to pass a start to the Ss and a stop to the Ks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to mention the most direct way: switch to runlevel 2.

```
telinit 2
```

If for some reason you don't want to do that, you could explicitly loop over the scripts.

```
for K in /etc/rc2.d/K*; do "$K" stop;  done
for S in /etc/rc2.d/S*; do "$S" start; done
```